# Can't load image from SVG image element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to load a image as the svg background, but it only shows a broken image, I think the path is correct(the js and the image files are under the same directory) and I tried adding `'data:image/png;base64,'` at the front it still didn't work, I also tried localhost, it didn't work neither.

```
  svg
  .append("image")
  .attr("width", "1352px")
  .attr("height", "721px")
  .attr("href", "img.png");
```

But I can load the image from `<img>` tag.
I change to canvas to display the image, and image still cannot be displayed.However, the application can display online image.

```
 let img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src =
  "img.png";
```

I am running the application on Chromium and using Parcel bundle.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think the problem is I am using Parcel, so I will need to import the image file.

```
import img from "./img.png";
```